# Как выделить точки на графике построенном в jupyter notebook с помощью matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, графика, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Мне надо построить график зависимости y от t и выделить на нем те точки, где y=0. Координаты у меня хранятся в списках y_t, y_p, соостветсвенно.
График я строю так `pyplot.plot(y_p, t_p)` и jupyter сразу его рисует.

Как мне выделить нужные точки на нем?

Comment: можете привести пример заполнения `y_p`, `t_p`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)
y = np.sin(np.cos(x)**3)
epsilon = 1e-3
mask = np.abs(y) < epsilon
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.scatter(x[mask], y[mask], color='orange', s=40, marker='o')
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]